# Highcharts - Column range chart does not render properly

Tags: highcharts

I've a highchart which displays categories on x-axis and time on y-axis.This chart does not show complete range for a particular set of dates. I've created a fiddle for the same. jsfiddle.net/kshrrgvo

For the series with name "Remaining" bars are not complete. Moreover, the axis labels does not denote the full range.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more the issue? I used a lot highcharts and it seems it's doing what you asked for....

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. This is creating the bars correctly. But for these particular dates, which comprise the series in the jsfiddle, the green bars are not rendering properly. For the second category "Series2", range spans from Oct 14 2015 to Sep 12 2020. But the chart shows axis only upto 2016.

Comment: Istead of empy array add index of point (x) for each data in this serie. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kshrrgvo/2/